# Select row by regex match in Idiorm and Paris

Tags: php, model, idiorm

I'm looking for following SQL equivalent in Idiorm and Paris:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (regex=0 AND col=_match_) OR (regex=1 AND _match_ REGEXP col)
LIMIT 1
```

Following Idiorm & Paris statements only matches `col=_match_`:

**Idiorm:**

```
$row = ORM::for_table('table')
->where_equal('col', '_match_')
->find_one()
```

**Paris:**

```
MyModel::where('col', '_match_')->find_one()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading docs and codes, it seems that Idiorm/Paris doesn't support that functionality. So, we have two options:

1. Using `where_raw()` method, which by this way we will pass where clause as a string directly to Idiorm.
2. Adding a new method like `where_condition()` to Idiorm ORM class which matches $value against $column_name by setting `$reverse = true`, otherwise, it's a normal where condition (that matches $column_name against $value).

   ```
   public function where_condition($column_name, $operator, $value, $reverse = false)
   {
   $multiple = is_array($column_name) ? $column_name : array($column_name => $value);
   $result = $this;

   foreach($multiple as $key => $val) {
       // Add the table name in case of ambiguous columns
       if (count($result->_join_sources) > 0 && strpos($key, '.') === false) {
           $table = $result->_table_name;
           if (!is_null($result->_table_alias)) {
               $table = $result->_table_alias;
           }

           $key = "{$table}.{$key}";
       }
       $key = $result->_quote_identifier($key);

       if($reverse)
           $result = $result->_add_condition('where', "? {$operator} {$key}", $val);
       else
          $result = $result->_add_condition('where', "{$key} {$operator} ?", $val); 
   }
   return $result;

   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

The sentence where_any is the solution for that
Example:

```
$myModel = ORM::for_table('table')
        ->where_any_is(array(
            array('regex'=> 0,'col' => 'match'),
            array('regex'=> 1,'col' => '_match_')))
        ->limit(1)->find_many();
```

See the docs oficial for filtering query: https://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/querying.html#filtering-results

Comment: Thank you Pastor for the code, It's really useful. But I'm looking to match as regular expression on rows that have a regex column equal to 1.